# How many closed polygons $n$ lines make on a plane?(not duplicate)

Tags: geometry

How many closed polygons will $n$ coplanar lines, all intersecting each other (no three concurrent), form on the plane?

Can we find a recursion formula for this?? Is there a way out?

Comment: I have edited it..

Comment: It is no more a duplicate problem..

Comment: Is it $\frac{n^2-3n+2}{2}$  ??

Comment: How did you get it?